# tf.train.Checkpoint is restoring or not?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am running tensorflow 2.4 on colab. I tried to save the model using `tf.train.Checkpoint()` since it includes model subclassing, but after restoration I saw It didn't restored any weights of my model.

Here are few snippets:

```
### From tensorflow tutorial nmt_with_attention
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, enc_units, batch_sz):
    ...
    self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(self.enc_units,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   return_state=True,
                                   recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')

.
.
.

class NMT_Train(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, inp_vocab_size, tar_vocab_size, max_length_inp, max_length_tar, emb_dims, units, batch_size, source_tokenizer, target_tokenizer):
    super(NMT_Train, self).__init__()
    self.encoder = Encoder(inp_vocab_size, emb_dims, units, batch_size)
    ...

.
.
.

model = NMT_Train(INP_VOCAB, TAR_VOCAB, MAXLEN, MAXLEN, EMB_DIMS, UNITS, BATCH_SIZE, english_tokenizer, hindi_tokenizer)
model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits= True))
model.fit(dataset, epochs=2)

checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(model = model)
manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(checkpoint, './ckpts', max_to_keep=1)
manager.save()

model.encoder.gru.get_weights() ### get the output
##[array([[-0.0627057 ,  0.05900152,  0.06614069, ...

model.optimizer.get_weights() ### get the output
##[90, array([[ 6.6851695e-05, -4.6736805e-06, -2.3183979e-05, ...
```

When I later restored it I didn't get any gru weights:

```
model = NMT_Train(INP_VOCAB, TAR_VOCAB, MAXLEN, MAXLEN, EMB_DIMS, UNITS, BATCH_SIZE, english_tokenizer, hindi_tokenizer)
model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits= True))

checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(model = model)
manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(checkpoint, './ckpts', max_to_keep=1)

manager.restore_or_initialize()

model.encoder.gru.get_weights() ### empty list
## []

model.optimizer.get_weights() ### empty list
## []
```

I also tried `checkpoint.restore(manager.latest_checkpoint)` but nothing changed.

Is there any thing wrong I am doing?? Or suggest any other way around to save the model so that I can retrain it for further epochs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining a keras model, so why do not use keras model chekpoints?

From [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/):

```py
model.compile(loss=..., optimizer=...,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

EPOCHS = 10
checkpoint_filepath = '/tmp/checkpoint'
model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor='val_accuracy',
    mode='max',
    save_best_only=True)

# Model weights are saved at the end of every epoch, if it's the best seen
# so far.
model.fit(epochs=EPOCHS, callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback])

# The model weights (that are considered the best) are loaded into the model.
model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)
```

Comment: Hey, I tried it but it still showed me the same thing :(. Also did this save the optimizer as I want to train it for further epochs again.

Comment: My Bad, everything is working fine. Maybe there were some delayed restorations. When i called the model on dummy sentence and then checked the weights, it showed my correct things. Thanks for the reply.